# Magento 1.9.3.2 Invalid Cron Expression

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

I hope someone can help because I'm really struggling. My Magento cron is throwing an error:

```
#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Schedule.php(68): Mage::exception('Mage_Cron', 'Invalid cron ex...')
#1 app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(858): Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule->setCronExpr('0 0 3 1/1 * ? *')
#2 app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(128): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->setCronExpr('0 0 3 1/1 * ? *')
#3 app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/ScheduleManager.php(254): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->initializeFromJob(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Job))
#4 app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/ScheduleManager.php(165): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_ScheduleManager->generateSchedulesForJob(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Job))
#5 app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(43): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_ScheduleManager->generateSchedules()
#6 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1300): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1281): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
cron.php(77): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#10 {main}
```

The problem I have is I just can't find the job that's got that cron expression! I've tried grep in my Magento directory for the expression but all I get is the error reports/logs.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

What you can find when you 'grep' through the filesystem is basically the default setting for a cron job.

Many extensions allow you to define the execution expression separately for example from `System -> Configuration`. Also, Aoe_Schedule allows you to modify the execution expression (from `System -> Scheduler -> Job Configuration`). These settings then should be stored in `core_config_data` table with a path like `crontab/jobs/CRON_CODE/schedule/cron_expr`.

So, to find the faulty cron expression you can try to `select * from core_config_data where value = "0 0 3 1/1 * ? *"` for example from within PHPMyAdmin.